# Словарь (переводчик) на android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, хочу написать что-то вроде словаря (англ-рус) на android. Хочу узнать, как можно связать словарь с гугл переводчиком (например) и можно ли потом как-то сохранять "слово-перевод" на самом устройстве? И какую коллекцию лучше для этого использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал что-то подобное полтора-два года назад, варианты были такими

- Google translate - хороший вариант, но платный
- Yandex translate -    бесплатный, но перевод не супер был
- Bing translate - тоже самое что яндекс, но перевод на русский еще  хуже(по моему субъективному мнению)
- Парсинг словарей которые есть в сети, и создание на этой основе своей базы. только проблема в том, что фразы  таким способом перевести не  получится, только слова.

В итоге для перевода слов я использовал свою базу, которую сформировал в основном по словарю Мюллера, и по другим которые нашел в сети, а фразы переводил с помощью яндекс переводчика.

Если вам побаловаться, то яндекс translate api хватит.
Данные храните в sqllite.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А не могли бы вы подсказать, где можно почерпнуть нужной инфы для создания подобного приложения? И можно ли с вами связаться, чтобы, вдруг чего, узнать совет понимающего в этом деле человека?

Comment: @111xbot111, Что вы имеете ввиду под нужой инфой?

1. Вам нужны знания java, основных фреймворков, ООП, знание основных алгоритмов и структур данных и т.д.  
2. Понимание и концепцию разработки под android.  
3. Знание sql и взаимодействие с БД.  
4. Дополнительно: изучить яндекс translate api.

Первые 3 пункта достаточно большие. И когда человек берется делать такое приложение, у него уже должен иметься опыт работы с java se и опыт работы с бд либо огромное желание научиться этому.

Comment: @Lookingfor если где-то в ступор войду. 1 освоил на достаточном уровне, 2 - азы освоил, в процессе буду углубляться. Вот с 3 и 4 у меня ноль, поэтому и хочу наставника, чтобы не втыкать долго в одну проблему, а быстро работать, с грамотными коррективами.

Comment: я могу рассмотреть этот вариант, но только с перечнем условий.. к примеру

1) Весь код будет под гитом и храниться в битбакете.
2) Разработка будет идти итерациями, каждая по 2 недели, перед каждой итерацией планирование, в конце каждой итерации готовый прототип
3) Конечная цель, выложить работающее, удобное приложение в google play
4) Вы тратите на разработку этого приложения не меньше 20-ти часов в неделю.

Как-то так, в противном случае мне нет смысла тратить свое время:) Поэтому если вас все это устраивает, то можете оставить здесь свои контакты я с вами свяжусь.